# Buscar no HTML estilo LIKE %..%

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu posso buscar em HTMLS estilo `LIKE %..%` tipo eu possuo estas divs com estes estilos

```
<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é fulana de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Alterbania de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Iscrovenia de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Lubiscréia de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>
```

Como eu posso buscar dentro de todas as classes nomeadas `texto_de_reportagem` o nome da `Lubiscréia` por exemplo? Ou se eu colocasse na "busca" a palavra `tal` ele iria me retornar todos os rows já que todos possuem a palavra `tal`... Da mesma forma que o MySQL trabalha entende?

Answer (score 4):

Cria uma função que procure por uma palavra numa lista de elementos.

Fiz um exemplo que aceita também opção de procurar respeitando (ou não) ter letra grande.

```
function encontrar(palavra, elementos, caseSensitive) {
    return [].filter.call(textos, function (texto) {
        var innerHTML = texto.innerHTML;
        if (!caseSensitive) {
            innerHTML = innerHTML.toLowerCase();
            palavra = palavra.toLowerCase();
        }
        return innerHTML.indexOf(palavra) != -1;
    });
}
```

O que esta função faz é procurar no `.innerHTML` de cada elemento pela posição da palavra que queres. Se ele não encontrar o [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) dá `-1`.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6q5uzhym/

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando apenas [javavascript](/questions/tagged/javavascript):

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var like = "Alterbania".toLowerCase(); // evitar case sensitive
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var encontrados = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
     if (divs[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(like) > -1) {
         encontrados.push(divs[i]);
     }
  }
  console.log(encontrados);
  alert("Encontrado: " + encontrados.length);
  return encontrados;
}
```

```html
<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é fulana de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Alterbania de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Iscrovenia de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Lubiscréia de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>
```

Utilizando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  /* ajusta o constains pra pegar case sensitive */
  jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase()) > -1;
  };  
  
  var like = "Alterbania".toLowerCase();
  var encontrados = $('div:contains("' + like + '")');
  console.log(encontrados);
  alert("Encontrado: " + encontrados.length);
  return encontrados;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é fulana de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Alterbania de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Iscrovenia de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>

<div class="texto_de_reportagem">Olá meu nome é Lubiscréia de tal e nasci assim vou morrer assim Fulaninhanhá..</div>
```

Comment: no caso do feito com jQuery, como eu reproduziria este efeito http://jsfiddle.net/x8rpY/1/ no seu código?

Comment: @user3163662 seria isso http://jsfiddle.net/x8rpY/800/?

Answer (score 0):

O exemplo abaixo retorna todos os divs com o valor "Lubiscréia".

```
$( "div:contains('Lubiscréia')" );
```

Ou ainda, filtrando pela classe:

```
$("span[class='texto_de_reportagem']").filter(":contains('Lubiscréia')");
```